# Origin of mesora for halachos covered in Seder Zeraim

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, mishna, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, rishonim

Other than *Berachos*, there is no *gemara* in *Seder Zer'aim*. Where then does our *mesora* for the *halachos* discussed in that *seder* come from? The *rishonim* do discuss them, but were did they get it from? Were the *rishonim* basing their *psak* directly on the *mishna*?

Comment: There is plenty of Yerushalmi on Zeraim, just no Bavli.

Comment: There is also plenty of Bavli analyzing sugyot in Zeraim, just not directly on those masechtot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rambam, the most prolific rishonic author of laws of Zeraim, writes as follows in his introduction to Mishneh Torah:

> ומשני הגמרות ומן התוספתות ומספרא וספרי (ומן התוספות) מכולם יתבאר האסור והמותר הטמא והטהור החיוב והפטור הפסול והכשר כמו שהעתיקו איש מפי איש מפי משה רבינו מסיני
>
> From the entire [body of knowledge stemming from] the two Talmuds, the Tosefta, the Sifra, and the Sifre, can be derived the forbidden and the permitted, the impure and the pure, the liable and those who are free of liability, the invalid and the valid as was received [in tradition], one person from another, [in a chain extending back] to Moses at Mount Sinai.
>
> ([Touger translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/901656/jewish/Introduction-to-Mishneh-Torah.htm))

> ואין צריך לומר הגמרא עצמה הבבלית והירושלמית וספרא וספרי והתוספתא שהם צריכין דעת רחבה ונפש חכמה וזמן ארוך ואחר כך יודע מהם הדרך הנכוחה בדברים האסורים והמותרים ושאר דיני התורה היאך הוא ומפני זה נערתי חצני אני משה בן מיימון הספרדי ונשענתי על הצור ברוך הוא ובינותי בכל אלו הספרים וראיתי לחבר דברים המתבררים מכל אלו החיבורים בענין האסור והמותר הטמא והטהור עם שאר דיני התורה. כולם בלשון ברורה ודרך קצרה עד שתהא תורה שבעל פה כולה סדורה בפי הכל בלא קושיא ולא פירוק
>
> Needless to say, [there is confusion] with regard to the Talmud itself - both the Jerusalem and Babylonian Talmuds - the Sifra, the Sifre, and the Tosefta, for they require a breadth of knowledge, a spirit of wisdom, and much time, for appreciating the proper path regarding what is permitted and forbidden, and the other laws of the Torah.
>
> Therefore, I girded my loins - I, Moses, the son of Maimon, of Spain.36 I relied upon the Rock, blessed be He. I contemplated all these texts and sought to compose [a work which would include the conclusions] derived from all these texts regarding the forbidden and the permitted, the impure and the pure, and the remainder of the Torah's laws, all in clear and concise terms, so that the entire Oral Law could be organized in each person's mouth without questions or objections.
>
> ([Touger translation](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/901656/jewish/Introduction-to-Mishneh-Torah.htm))

If all laws are derived from the list of above mentioned sources then presumably where one of those sources does not exist the laws are derived from the remainder of the list.